# Relations error in .NET Core using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I created a relationship between `Users` and `TodoItems`, but when I try to add, I get the error shown below.

```cs
long id = 1;
var user = _context.Users.Find(id);
user.TodoItems.Add(todoItem);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My models:

```cs
public class TodoItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TodoItem>? TodoItems { get; set; }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> error: The User field is required.

I'm using Entity Framework Core with Ngpsql.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you get `todoItem` so I can only guess, but the error suggests that you need to set the `User` property on `todoItem`. You should probably also use an `Include` when you get the user to make sure that the todo items are loaded.

Comment: todoItem comes from the body of the POST request, TodoItem has a One-To-Many relationship with Users, so what I did is the same as the Entity Framework documentation

Comment: Check the incoming `todoItem` to see if the `User` property is set. If not, then you'll need to set it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `TodoItems` property of `User` loaded?  Doesn't seem so and I'm not entirely sure how latest EF Core handles such a situation.  You can try eager loading the collection to see if that helps

```
var user = _context.Users
    .Include( u => u.TodoItems )
    .FirstOrDefault( u => u.Id == id ); 

// check for null result
if( user is null )
{
    // invalid user id
}
```

Or you can set the `User` property of the `ToDoItem`

```
var user = _context.Users.Find(id); // you should check for null result
todoItem.User = user;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If you don't need the `user` entity for anything else, you can just fudge it with a quick instantiation setting only the PK value(s):

```
todoItem.User = new User { Id = id };
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Still no guarantees the `id` is valid but you could either handle the thrown exception or check if it exists first without loading the entire entity from the backing store.  For example, wrap the above in

```
if( _context.Users.Any( u => u.Id == id ) )
{
    ...
}
else
{
    // handle invalid user id
}
```

Comment: thanks, bro, the second code described by you worked, thank you very much.